# Can I make Cornerstone run make and cancel the commit if it fails?

Tags: svn, version-control, makefile, cornerstone

I have a Makefile in my working copy. Can I make Cornerstone run `make; make test` before a commit, and cancel the commit if make fails?

This way I'm sure I don't accidentally commit code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cornerstone 2.5.x supports [pre-commit scripts](http://www.zennaware.com/blog/2011/07/release-notes-2_5/), presumably you could attach a script that runs the make file to that.

Comment: Will Cornerstone cancel the commit if the script fails?

Comment: That wasn't clear to me from the Cornerstone docs, but I'm assuming that Cornerstone uses [svn hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks). A pre-commit hook cancels the commit if it returns with a non-zero value.